# htaccess rewrite to require www, https, and ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, forwarding

I am trying to figure out how to write the .htaccess so that all URLs:
1) Use https
2) Forward from http://example.com to https://www.example.com
3) Forward from the server IP to the domain

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^111\.11\.111\.111
RewriteRule ^ https://www.{HTTP_HOST}/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But this doesn't work. The IP is the actual server IP.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do all this in a single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```